# Get type of typed property in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have a `DTO` with typed PHP variables:

```
class CreateMembershipInputDto extends BaseDto
{
    public bool $is_gift;
    public int $year;
    public string $name;
    public \DateTime $shipping_date;
    public ContactInputDto $buyer;
    public ?ContactInputDto $receiver;
}
```

I am trying to make some kind of automapper, which fills the properties, but I need to check the type of the variable but that seems to be impossible.

```
class BaseDto
{
    public function __construct($json)
    {
        $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
        foreach($jsonArray as $key=>$value){
            $type = gettype($this->$key);
            if($type instanceof BaseDto)
                $this->$key = new $type($value);
            else
                $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

**ContactInputDto:**

```
class ContactInputDto extends BaseDto
{
    public string $firstname;
    public string $lastname;
    public string $street_housenumber;
    public string $postal_code;
    public string $place;
    public string $country;
    public string $email;
    public string $phone;
}
```

Is it somehow possible to make that line `"gettype($this->$key)"` work, without php throwing the following error:

> Typed property App\Dto\CreateMembershipInputDto::$is_gift must not be accessed before initialization

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the manual does not seem to currently document it, there is a method added to [`ReflectionProperty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php) to allow you to get the type. This is actually specified in the [RFC for typed properties](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2)

Here's how you would use it:

```php
class CreateMembershipInputDto extends BaseDto {
    public bool $is_gift;
    public int $year;
    public string $name;
    public \DateTime $shipping_date;
    public ContactInputDto $buyer;
    public ?ContactInputDto $receiver;
}

class BaseDto
{
    public function __construct($json)
    {   
        $r = new \ReflectionClass(static::class); //Static should resolve the the actual class being constructed
        $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
        foreach($jsonArray as $key=>$value){
            $prop = $r->getProperty($key);
            if (!$prop || !$prop->getType()) { continue; } // Not a valid property or property has no type   
            $type = $prop->getType();
            if($type->getName() === BaseDto::class) //types names are strings
                $this->$key = new $type($value);
            else
                $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to check if the type extends `BaseDto` you will need `(new \ReflectionClass($type->getName()))->isSubclassOf(BaseDto::class)`

Note that `getName` refers to to [`ReflectionNamedType::getName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php). Prior to PHP 8 this was the only possible instance you could get `$prop->getType()` however starting PHP 8 you may also get a [`ReflectionUnionType`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionuniontype.php) which contains multiple types

Comment: getProperty method throws a ReflectionException if there is no property with such a name. Better to catch that like that:
`try{ $prop = $r->getProperty($key); } catch (ReflectionException $e) { continue; } // Property does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way than the excepted answer.

```
<?php
class User
{
    public string $name;
}

$rp = new ReflectionProperty('User', 'name');
echo $rp->getType()->getName();
?>
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.gettype.php